# How can I capture the last group in a multiline file using a regular expression?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to use a regular expression to grab parts of a subtitle file. They come in this format:

```
1
00:00:38,505 --> 00:00:40,438
<i>I'm not gonna bullshit you.</i>

...

1029
01:37:20,223 --> 01:37:23,023
No thanks.
```

The text can take up multiple lines.

Here's what I'm currently using:

```
(\d+?)\r\n(\d+?):(\d+?):(\d+?),(\d+?) --> (\d+?):(\d+?):(\d+?),(\d+?)\r\n(?<content>(.+)(\r\n)*\D*)[\r\n|$]*?
```

It's capturing all the groups properly, but it's leaving out the last match. So if there are 1029 subtitles in the text file, it's finding 1028 of them. The file ends after the </i> in the example I provided. It's the only group that is *not* being captured.

Can anyone help me with this? I thought that since it wasn't specified as multiline that "$" would act as "End of File", but I seem to be wrong there.

Comment: Is it related to `r` language ? Why this tag ?

Comment: The `$` character in a character class `[]` means a literal `$` and not an assertion for the end of string/line.

Comment: I'd recommend `(?m)^(\d+)\r?\n(\d+?):(\d+):(\d+),(\d+) --> (\d+):(\d+):(\d+),(\d+)\r?\n(?<content>[\s\S]*?)(?=\r?\n\d+$|\z)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/DwQAO7/1)

Comment: Once you have time to test out my suggestion, please drop a comment below my answer, will you?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew unfortunately it doesn't work in .NET. \z is not a recognized character, and if $ and ^ are supposed to match line starts/ends, you're missing a few.

Comment: @DannyBoy It works, you just need to make sure `$` is always preceded with `\r?` in the multiline mode. I updated the answer with the right .NET regex and its declaration in C#. Always define regex patterns using verbatim string literals. Learn strings before using regex, or you will stumble on too many simple basic issues.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sorry for the wait! I'm new to posting on here. Thank you for your excellent help and I've upvoted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(?sm)^(\d+)\r?\n(\d+?):(\d+):(\d+),(\d+) --> (\d+):(\d+):(\d+),(\d+)\r?\n(?<content>.*?)(?=\r?\n\d+\r?$|\z)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3fsm%29%5e%28%5cd%2b%29%5cr%3f%5cn%28%5cd%2b%3f%29%3a%28%5cd%2b%29%3a%28%5cd%2b%29%2c%28%5cd%2b%29+--%3e+%28%5cd%2b%29%3a%28%5cd%2b%29%3a%28%5cd%2b%29%2c%28%5cd%2b%29%5cr%3f%5cn%28%3f%3ccontent%3e.*%3f%29%28%3f%3d%5cr%3f%5cn%5cd%2b%5cr%3f%24%7c%5cz%29&i=1%0d%0a00%3a00%3a38%2c505+--%3e+00%3a00%3a40%2c438%0d%0a%3ci%3eI.%3c%2fi%3e%0d%0a...%0d%0a%0d%0a1029%0d%0a01%3a37%3a20%2c223+--%3e+01%3a37%3a23%2c023%0d%0aNo&o=m).

**Details**

- `(?sm)` - enable anchors matching at the start and end of each line (with `m`) and dot matching newline (with `s`)
- `^` - start of a line
- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits
- `\r?\n` - a CRLF or LF ending
- `(\d+):(\d+):(\d+),(\d+) --> (\d+):(\d+):(\d+),(\d+)` - 1+ digits (Group 2), `:`, 1+ digits (Group 3), `:`, 1+ digits (Group 4), `,`, 1+ digits (Group 5), `-->` enclosed with 1 space, 1+ digits (Group 6), `:`, 1+ digits (Group 7), `:`, 1+ digits (Group 8), `,`, 1+ digits (Group 9)
- `\r?\n` - a CRLF or LF ending
- `(?<content>.*?)` - Group "content" that matches any 0+ chars as few as possible up to the first
- `(?=\r?\n\d+\r?$|\z)` - CRLF or LF ending, 1+ digits and end of line or end of string.

C# code snippet:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(text, @"(?sm)^(\d+)\r?\n(\d+?):(\d+):(\d+),(\d+) --> (\d+):(\d+):(\d+),(\d+)\r?\n(?<content>.*?)(?=\r?\n\d+\r?$|\z)");
```